# Adding waypoints with certain connected data

Tags: qgis, excel

Is it possible to import excel data to QGIS?

I have an 80,000 point database with city names (no coordinates) in a common country. There would possibly be minimal data to be viewed from each point.

How would I handle the import?

---

Here is a screenshot. It has been a few years since I last used QGIS, so I'm sure that I have forgotten some of the important basics.

[image: Chilobwe]

If you can get me on the right track, I can take it from there. I have reduced my dataset to a single point, and I wish to add it to an existing country shapefile which I already have.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

**Update** : Based on the screenshot, it looks like the first record of your file doesn't have the field names. And also your coordinate data is in degrees, minutes and seconds. Try the following steps to solve your issue -

1. Uncheck the '*First record has field name*' option
2. Now you'll have the column names in the form of '*field_1, field_2*' etc. Select the respective columns from the dropdown for *X field* and *Y field*.
3. Check the *DMS coordinates* option. (This tells QGIS that the coordinates are expressed in minutes/degree/seconds).

You can take a look at the following screenshot for reference -

[image]

Comment: My database is simply a list of cities and country. I save the excel file as a delimited text file, but when I try to import it into QGIS, I get a message that there was no data found (in the file). Is this a Macintosh issue (I read an earlier account suggesting that possibility)?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the window where you are adding the delimited text file and where you are getting this error?

Comment: How do I add a screenshot or file on the forum?

Comment: You can edit your question and add an image of your screenshot there.

Comment: OK I will try. Sorry, I don't see the opportunity to add an attachment.

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes. I got a dataset to be represented. Thanks for your help.